# could not initialize a memory primitive descriptor, in file tensorflow/core/kernels/mkl_relu_op.cc:873

Tags: python, tensorflow

I was try to copy a code which implement adaptive gradient

error comes from this code

```
    for i, n_hidden in enumerate(n_hiddens):
    if i == 0:
        input = x
        input_dim = n_in
    else:
        input = output
        input_dim = n_hiddens[i - 1]

    W = weight_variable([input_dim, n_hidden])
    b = bias_variable([n_hidden])

    h = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(input, W) + b)
    output = tf.nn.dropout(h, keep_prob)
```

at

```
h = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(input, w) + b)
```

and the interpreter said

```
AbortedError (see above for traceback): Operation received an exception:Status: 3, message: could not initialize a memory primitive descriptor, in file tensorflow/core/kernels/mkl_relu_op.cc:873
 [[{{node Relu}} = _MklRelu[T=DT_FLOAT, _kernel="MklOp", _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](add, DMT/_0)]]
```

there's other errors too, but error occur same like that.

I was really good at copying this code, so I think there's nothing special mistake at code but I can't confirm it.
I think that something wrong at 'relu' function which comes with tensorflow, but I don't know what to do.

---

here is my full code, if you need

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.utils import shuffle
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

np.random.seed(0)
tf.set_random_seed(1234)

def inference(x, keep_prob, n_in, n_hiddens, n_out):
    def weight_variable(shape):
        initial = np.sqrt(2.0 / shape[0]) * tf.truncated_normal(shape)
        return tf.Variable(initial)

    def bias_variable(shape):
        initial = tf.zeros(shape)
        return tf.Variable(initial)

    for i, n_hidden in enumerate(n_hiddens):
        if i == 0:
            input = x
            input_dim = n_in
        else:
            input = output
            input_dim = n_hiddens[i - 1]

        W = weight_variable([input_dim, n_hidden])
        b = bias_variable([n_hidden])

        h = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(input, W) + b)
        output = tf.nn.dropout(h, keep_prob)

    W_out = weight_variable([n_hiddens[-1], n_out])
    b_out = bias_variable([n_out])
    y = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(output, W_out) + b_out)
    return y

def loss(y, t):
    cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(-tf.reduce_sum(t * tf.log(tf.clip_by_value(y, 1e-10, 1.0)), reduction_indices=[1]))
    return cross_entropy

def training(loss):
    optimizer = tf.train.AdagradOptimizer(0.01)
    train_step = optimizer.minimize(loss)
    return train_step

def accuracy(y, t):
    correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y, 1), tf.argmax(t, 1))
    accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))
    return accuracy

if __name__ == '__main__':
    mnist = datasets.fetch_mldata('MNIST original')

    n = len(mnist.data)
    N = 30000
    N_train = 20000
    N_validation = 4000
    indices = np.random.permutation(range(n))[:N]

    X = mnist.data[indices]
    X = X / 255.0
    X = X - X.mean(axis=1).reshape(len(X), 1)
    y = mnist.target[indices]
    Y = np.eye(10)[y.astype(int)]

    X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, train_size=N_train)

    X_train, X_validation, Y_train, Y_validation = train_test_split(X_train, Y_train, test_size=N_validation)

    n_in = len(X[0])
    n_hiddens = [200, 200, 200]
    n_out = len(Y[0])
    p_keep = 0.5

    x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, n_in])
    t = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, n_out])
    keep_prob = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)

    y = inference(x, keep_prob, n_in=n_in, n_hiddens=n_hiddens, n_out=n_out)
    loss = loss(y, t)
    train_step = training(loss)

    accuracy = accuracy(y, t)

    history = {'val_loss' : [], 'val_acc' : []}

    epochs = 50
    batch_size = 200

    init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
    sess = tf.Session()
    sess.run(init)

    n_batches = N_train // batch_size

    for epoch in range(epochs):
        X_, Y_ = shuffle(X_train, Y_train)

        for i in range(n_batches):
            start = i * batch_size
            end = start + batch_size

            sess.run(train_step, feed_dict = {x : X_[start:end], t : Y_[start:end], keep_prob : p_keep})

        val_loss = loss.eval(session=sess, feed_dict = {x : X_validation, t : Y_validation, keep_prob : 1.0})
        val_acc = accuracy.eval(session = sess, feed_dict = {x : X_validation, t : Y_validation, keep_prob : 1.0})

        history['val_loss'].append(val_loss)
        history['val_acc'].append(val_acc)

        print('epoch : ', epoch, ' validation loss : ', val_loss, ' validation accuracy : ', val_acc)

    plt.rc('font', family = 'serif')
    fig = plt.figure()
    plt.plot(range(epochs), history['val_loss'], label = 'loss', color = 'black')
    plt.xlabel('epochs')
    plt.show()

    accuracy_rate = accuracy.eval(session = sess, feed_dict = {x : X_test, t : Y_test, keep_prob : 1.0})
    print('accuracy : ', accuracy_rate)
```

and here is my whole error log

```
 /home/shin/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_split.py:2069: FutureWarning: From version 0.21, test_size will always complement train_size unless both are specified.
  FutureWarning)
2018-11-05 18:11:21.403663: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:141] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: SSE4.1 SSE4.2 AVX AVX2 FMA
2018-11-05 18:11:21.406748: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/process_util.cc:69] Creating new thread pool with default inter op setting: 2. Tune using inter_op_parallelism_threads for best performance.
2018-11-05 18:11:22.406667: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1273] OP_REQUIRES failed at mkl_relu_op.cc:876 : Aborted: Operation received an exception:Status: 3, message: could not initialize a memory primitive descriptor, in file tensorflow/core/kernels/mkl_relu_op.cc:873
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/shin/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1292, in _do_call
    return fn(*args)
  File "/home/shin/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1277, in _run_fn
    options, feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list, run_metadata)
  File "/home/shin/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1367, in _call_tf_sessionrun
    run_metadata)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.AbortedError: Operation received an exception:Status: 3, message: could not initialize a memory primitive descriptor, in file tensorflow/core/kernels/mkl_relu_op.cc:873
     [[{{node Relu}} = _MklRelu[T=DT_FLOAT, _kernel="MklOp", _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](add, DMT/_0)]]

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/shin/pythonClass/AdaGrad.py", line 105, in <module>
    sess.run(train_step, feed_dict = {x : X_[start:end], t : Y_[start:end], keep_prob : p_keep})
  File "/home/shin/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 887, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "/home/shin/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1110, in _run
    feed_dict_tensor, options, run_metadata)
  File "/home/shin/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1286, in _do_run
    run_metadata)
  File "/home/shin/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1308, in _do_call
    raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.AbortedError: Operation received an exception:Status: 3, message: could not initialize a memory primitive descriptor, in file tensorflow/core/kernels/mkl_relu_op.cc:873
     [[{{node Relu}} = _MklRelu[T=DT_FLOAT, _kernel="MklOp", _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](add, DMT/_0)]]

Caused by op 'Relu', defined at:
  File "/home/shin/pythonClass/AdaGrad.py", line 81, in <module>
    y = inference(x, keep_prob, n_in=n_in, n_hiddens=n_hiddens, n_out=n_out)
  File "/home/shin/pythonClass/AdaGrad.py", line 31, in inference
    h = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(input, W) + b)
  File "/home/shin/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_nn_ops.py", line 6780, in relu
    "Relu", features=features, name=name)
  File "/home/shin/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 787, in _apply_op_helper
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/home/shin/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/deprecation.py", line 488, in new_func
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/shin/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 3272, in create_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/home/shin/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1768, in __init__
    self._traceback = tf_stack.extract_stack()

AbortedError (see above for traceback): Operation received an exception:Status: 3, message: could not initialize a memory primitive descriptor, in file tensorflow/core/kernels/mkl_relu_op.cc:873
     [[{{node Relu}} = _MklRelu[T=DT_FLOAT, _kernel="MklOp", _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](add, DMT/_0)]]
```